# If F(x)=$\int_0^xf(x)dx$ for $x\in[0,3]$, find $F$. Find $F'(x)$ at all points where $F'$ exists.

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Let $f$ is given by $$ f(x)=\begin{cases}
               x,~~~ 0\leq x \leq 1\\
               1, ~~~1\leq x\leq 2 \\
               x, ~~~2<x\leq 3
            \end{cases}$$
If F(x)=$\int_0^xf(x)dx$ for $x\in[0,3]$, find $F$. Find $F'(x)$ at all points where $F'$ exists.

Attempt:

As f has only one point of discontinuity at $x=2$, so f is Riemann integrable on $[0,3]$.
Then 
$$ F(x)=\begin{cases}
               \int_0^x x\, dx,~~~ 0\leq x \leq 1\\
               \int_0^x 1\,  dx, ~~~1<x\leq 2 \\
               \int_0^x x\,  dx, ~~~2<x\leq 3
            \end{cases}=\begin{cases}
               \frac{x^2}{2},~~~ 0\leq x \leq 1\\
             x-1/2, ~~~1<x\leq 2 \\
              x^2/2-1/2, ~~~2<x\leq 3
            \end{cases}$$

As $f$ is not continuous, then by Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, $F$ is not differentiable everywhere on $[0, 3]$. If the above correct, please help for remaining part.

Comment: While the final result of your computation of $F(x)$ is correct, the intermediate step should be:
$$ F(x)=\begin{cases}
               \int_0^x x\, dx,~~~ 0\leq x \leq 1\\
               \int_0^1 x\,dx +\int_1^x 1\, dx, ~~~1<x\leq 2 \\
               \int_0^1 x\, dx +\int_1^2 1\, dx +\int_2^x x\, dx, ~~~2<x\leq 3
            \end{cases}$$

Answer (score 2):

Your computations for $F$ are correct. Now look at the intervals $[0,1),(1,2)$ and $(2,3]$. By the  Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, $F$ is differentiable on these intervals. It is your turn to investigate the differentiability of $F$ at the points $1$ and $2$.

Comment: Thank you. looking at the intervals [0,1),(1,2) and (2,3] we see that f is continuous at each of the intervals. Please explore "By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, F is differentiable on these intervals".

Comment: Ooops , a typo, my fault !

Comment: Its ok I understand. Please explore "By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, F is differentiable on these intervals" Are you want to mention as f in continuous on [0,1),(1,2) and (2,3], then by Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, F is differentiable on those intervals.